# How to get rid of blank line between grid rows in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Notice the blank (dark blue) line between row 0 and row 1 in this image...

[image]

I am not sure where this row comes from, but how do I get rid of it so the two rows have no spacing between them?

Here is the XAML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:WP.MobileMidstream.Device.Pages"
             x:Class="WP.MobileMidstream.Device.Pages.LoginPage"             
             Visual="Material">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#00458C" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" 
              Padding="0"
              Margin="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="23" />
                <RowDefinition Height="56" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <BoxView Color="Red" 
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.Column="0"                      
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                     Margin="0" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   BackgroundColor="RosyBrown"
                   Margin="0"
                   FontSize="20"
                   TextColor="White">Daily Run Sheet</Label>
            <Image Source="hamburger_icon" 
                   Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="0" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have wrong ColSpan and Column assignment for the second row:

```
 <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               BackgroundColor="RosyBrown"
               Margin="0"
               FontSize="20"
               TextColor="White">Daily Run Sheet</Label>
        <Image Source="hamburger_icon" 
               Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0" />
```

**Update:** 
Try setting the RowSpacing to be 0 on grid.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I have the grid set up like I need.  The Label spans two columns and centers itself on the device screen.  The hamburger menu is in Row 1, Col 0 and appears 'over' the label if that makes sense.  Also, I tried your XAML and have the same issue with the skinny gap between row 0 and row 1.

Comment: Oh oh! I think, I found the issue.

Put the vertical option of the Label to be Fill and Expand. Then that should cover the cell with your Label background color. I think this must fix it.

Comment: Oops, RowSpacing was the culprit!  Thanks!

Comment: Then put the Hamburger vertical option to be center

Comment: Oh really! Thank god that I mentioned that too.